# Python: why is __dict__ attribute not in built-in class instances

Tags: python

If my understanding of the Python data model is correct, both classes and class instances have associated `__dict__` objects which contain all the attributes.  However, I'm a little confused as to why certain class instances, such as instances of `str` for example, don't have a `__dict__` attribute.

If I create a custom class:

```
class Foo:
     def __init__(self):
             self.firstname = "John"
             self.lastname = "Smith"
```

Then I can get the instance variables by saying:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> print(f.__dict__)
{'lastname': 'Smith', 'firstname': 'John'}
```

But if I try to do the same with an instance of the built-in `str`, I get:

```
>>> s = "abc"
>>> print(s.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

So, why don't instances of `str` have a `__dict__` attribute?

Comment: To elaborate on this, if every dict had a `__dict__`, then there would have to be `__dict__.__dict__` as well -- how deep should the recursion go?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instances of types defined in C don't have a __dict__ attribute by default.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this:

You can get the equivalent of a read only `__dict__` using this:

```
{s:getattr(x, s) for s in dir(x)}
```

EDIT: Please note that this may contain more entries than `__dict__`. To avert this, you may use this as a workaround:

```
{s:getattr(x, s) for s in dir(x) if not s.startswith("__")}
```

Comment: It should be `{s:getattr(x,s) for s in dir(x)}`, and it incudes entries not in the `__dict__`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a big improvement, and would now work in many cases.  However, if the object contains functions, `__dict__` will not return those functions, but `{s:getattr(x, s) for s in dir(x) if not s.startswith("__")}` will.  Example: `class A(): def b(): pass`

Comment: It will also list class-level variables that `__dict__` wont list.