# Why are instances of the `object` class immutable in Python?

Tags: python, attributes, immutability

```
>>> a = object()
>>> a.x = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'x'
>>> b = lambda:0
>>> b.x = 5
>>> b.x
5
```

Why do instances of the `object` class not have a `__dict__`, causing it to behave as semantically immutable? What were the reasons for choosing this design?

Specifically, why:

> instances of types defined in C don't have a __dict__ attribute by
>   default.

As noted in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502290/4562156)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: why is \_\_dict\_\_ attribute not in built-in class instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502183/python-why-is-dict-attribute-not-in-built-in-class-instances)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for [Python 2 is not very helpful](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object) in giving an explanation as to why you cannot assign attributes to an `object()`, but the documentation for [Python 3 provides a bit more information](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#object):

> Return a new featureless object. object is a base for all classes. It has the methods that are common to all instances of Python classes. This function does not accept any arguments.
>
> Note: **object does not have a** `__dict__`, **so you can’t assign arbitrary attributes to an instance of the object class**.

Thus, the reason you cannot add arbitrary attributes to your `object()` appears to be because of the fact that `object()` instances do not have an implementation of the `__dict__` attribute, not because `object()` instances are immutable:

```
>>> hasattr(object(), '__dict__')
False
>>>
```

Another interesting thing, but perhaps not relevant to the discussion at hand, is that while an **instance** of object may not have a `__dict__` implementation, the `object` class itself does:

```
>>> hasattr(object, '__dict__')
True
```

As for the *why* part of the question, I cannot find any exact  reasons for why `object()` doesn't have a `__dict__`. Is is probably because - as @tdelany has already mentioned on in the comments - an implementation detail. If you really want a definitive answer, you should [ask Guido himself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/818274/guido-van-rossum).

Comment: @SeanPianka No. But I'm still looking. I thought it would be useful to show why you cannot add attributes to an `object()`.

Comment: Because it is a builtin class.

Comment: `object` is implemented in C and its common that extension objects don't take extra attributes. Considering that regular class instance `__dict__` is an object, its not surprising the `object` doesnt have one!

Comment: @SeanPianka Like I said, I'm still workin' on it. Gimme some time :)

Comment: I think the answer is good... the docs say you can't do it and the reason is an implementation detail. You may find that it does work for other implementations.

Comment: @tdelaney Well I'll do a quick search anyways.

Comment: @leaf - here's a good place: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Include/object.h. It will show you the details of the implementation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. But I sort of wish I could have come up with a logical explanation as to why `object()` doesn't have a `__dict__` method. But I guess calling on Guido is the logical :)