# Is it possible to create a python object which does not have either a __slots__ nor a __dict__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slots

Is it possible to create a python object which does not have either a `__slots__` a `__dict__`?

Comment: Do you want to restrict access to the class' members? If so, and if you're stuck with python, then you're SOL.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502183/python-why-is-dict-attribute-not-in-built-in-class-instances) python classes defined in C have no `__dict__` attribute. So yeah, it is possible and this is how you get built-in classes that don't have it, such as `str`.

Other than that... if you look at the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) the `__dict__` is used to hold the namespace for user defined modules, classes and functions. So you'll get that attribute even when you define a new class that inherits from a built in class which doesn't have it. (such as str)

```
>>> class ob(str):
...    pass
... 
>>> o = ob()
>>> o.__dict__
{}
```